# Why do you bracket the entire line after a df subset that uses .isin() instead of just bracketing the df subset half?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

Why is it ok to write this:

```
example1 = df_name[df_name[['column1','column2']].isin(['val1', 'val2'])]
print(example1)
```

but not this:

```
example1 = df_name[df_name[['column1','column2']]].isin(['val1', 'val2'])
print(example1)
```

I was hoping to better understand filtering syntax, insofar as why you don't append something like .isin() to an entire (subsetted) df, instead of including it within the bracketed df subsection itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that can be done in `df[ ... ]` is supply a boolean array that is then used to select rows.  `df_name[['column1','column2']].isin(['val1', 'val2'])` does just that by creating a boolean array as output.  But `df_name[df_name[['column1','column2']]]` will fail because `df[...]` doesn't know how to use a DataFrame as a filter/selector.